# Query to see the privileges for a DB2 table

Tags: db2, toad, db2-zos

I'm just looking for a simple query to see the privileges set for the table .(I have to query it through TOAD for DB2)
  Note that this link is for the mainframe DB2/z.

select * from SYSIBM. ????

Comment: Which link? Do you need it for LUW or z?

Comment: `SYSTABAUTH`, no?

Comment: @data_henrik it is for "z"